# Internet Explorer 11: Files not downloading, '"filename" could not be downloaded'

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, download, internet-explorer-11

On a website that I have made for a client they are unable to download files from the site when they try to do so using Internet Explorer 11.

The files are held on our server and using a database of uploaded files, location, name and MIME type the file is able to be downloaded. For example the path is '/uploaded_files/6f/ae69bd966ba4c740b8073ff969a5425b', the filename is 'Finland Test 123.docx' and the MIME type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'.

This works fine for me when I try from both my home and work computer as well as others in our office. I have tired this on both in many browsers, including IE11, Firefox and Chrome.

They are getting the error returned as shown in the following image: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odf0j.png). The weird thing is the filename is completely wrong and that it works fine for us.

I'm assuming because of this the issue may lie with their internet settings or IE settings but I don't know what to suggest to them to try and resolve the issue (changing browser to Chrome, etc, is not an option).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the response headers as captured with a tool like Fiddler? - You could find an html page with a link to a static docx somewhere, have them right-click-save-as to eliminate any issues with Office/content filtering.

Comment: I can only really get the response headers from the Chrome Dev Tools due to the nature of the side and I can only get them from me, not from the client that is having issues.

If it's any help though, please find them below:

Cache-Control:private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Finland Test 123.docx"
Content-Length:12825
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Date:Wed, 01 Feb 2017 13:32:54 GMT
expires:-1
pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx
Vary:Authorization

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.In here i am downloading a pdf file stored in a crm record (annotation).

```
if (attachment != null)
{
    byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.documentbody.ToString());

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Sample");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
    Response.End();
}
```